# Finding highest values in a Poisson distribution in R

Tags: r

I do have a script in R that provides me predictions for football matches.
It uses a Poisson Distribution formula to find the results that are most likely to happen in a match, and working on them, u can find who wins or lose (if you sum the probabilities for 1-0,2-0,2-1, etc... u find the chance of winning for team1, and so on...)

What I do need is to identify the 2 highest values inside the poisson distribution table and their relative "fathers".

I mean, as you see in the pic here I should identify 0.08652817 and 0.07346077 and thei relative "fathers" (3-2 and 4-2)

[image: poisson distribution example]

So the script should provide something like

```
1°: 0,0865 (3-2)
2°: 0,073 (4-2)
```

I tried using

```
max(match, na.rm=T)
```

but obviously it just shows  0,0865 and not it's "father" (3-2)
I do need the same also for the second highest value.

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome! could you please provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the packages dplyr and purrr:

```
m <- matrix(ncol=7, nrow=7, runif(49)) #Fake data that look like your probabilities
d <- expand.grid(home=1:7, away=1:7) #data.frame with all possible outcomes
d$prob <- purrr::pmap_dbl(d, function(home, away){m[home,away]}) 
dplyr::top_n(d, 3, prob)
```